# ¿por que una petición funciona con text/plain y no con application/json?

Tags: ajax, reactjs, http

Estoy tratando de realizar una petición `POST` con el método `fetch` en un proyecto de **`react`**, el cual al realizar la petición.

Regresa el siguiente mensaje.

> CORS Preflight Did Not Succeed
>
> Solicitud de origen cruzado bloqueada: La política de mismo origen (Same Origin Policy) no permite la lectura de recursos remotos en [URLBack]

pero al realizar la petición desde una pagina de prueba utilizando **AJAX** funciona sin problema alguno.

Revisando el código en **react** se tiene lo siguiente.

```
headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json'
},
```

en **AJAX**

```
headers: {
    'Content-type': 'text/plain'
},
```

Entonces el problema es `text/plain` el cual el backend acepta y no marca el problema antes mencionado.
¿Es seguro usar `text/plain` en lugar de `application/json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que quiere decir es que la política [*Same Origin Policy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_politica), está bloqueando la petición

Normalmente es un error de puertos, por ejemplo

| Origen | Destino | Resultado | Razón |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| https://localhost/ | https://localhost/dir | Mismo origen | - |
| http://localhost | https://localhost | Error | Diferente protocolo |
| http://localhost | http://localhost:81 | Error | Puertos diferentes |

Se consideran `HTTP` y `HTTPS` protocolos diferentes, pues `http` es un protocolo que permite la comunicación y `https` es el protocolo para navegar de forma segura

Para navegar por `https`, se debe tener un [certificado de seguridad (SSL)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seguridad_de_la_capa_de_transporte) instalado en dicho servidor, este es emitido por una [entidad certificadora (CA)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoridad_de_certificaci%C3%B3n), el certificado tiene detalles como

| Dato | Descripción |
| --- | --- |
| Fecha de emisión | La fecha exacta de emisión del certificado |
| Fecha de expiración | La fecha exacta de expiración del certificado |
| Nombre Común | El dominio o dominios a ser validados |

Entonces, por motivos de seguridad, no se puede

- Hacer una petición desde HTTP a HTTPS
- Hacer una petición desde HTTPS a HTTP
- Hacer una petición entre puertos diferentes

---

Además, el encabezado `Content-Type` debería ser enviada por el servidor y no por el cliente, pues este encabezado es el que determina el tipo de archivo

En su lugar debería ser enviado `accept`

```js
fetch("url", {headers:{accept:"application/json"}})
```

**(`fetch` NO es un método de react. [Es un método nativo de Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch))**

---

> ¿Es seguro usar text/plain en lugar de application/json?

Me parecería que eso sería basado en opiniones, pero trataré de dar un punto relativamente conciso que no parezca una opinión

**Ninguno es mejor que otro, pues son tipos MIME totalmente distintos**

El tipo `application/json` es exclusivamente para archivos `.json` o podría ser enviado por el servidor y `text/plain` es para archivos de texto plano, sin ningún tipo de reglas específicas

Entonces, **ninguno es más seguro que otro**

---

#### Aclaraciones

**¿Qué es Content-Type?**

Es un tipo de encabezado normalmente proporcionado por el servidor, este encabezado sirve para identificar [el tipo MIME de un archivo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types)

El proceso es el siguiente

```
Petición -> Retenida por el navegador -> Navegador hace petición OPTIONS -> De ser aprobada, el navegador libera la petición original
```

La petición de tipo OPTIONS es un tipo de petición que hacen mayormente los navegadores para obtener la lista de orígenes admitidos de un dominio

Es decir, saber si el *dominio b* permite peticiones desde el *dominio a*

Este sería un tema de [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Esta es una política de compartimiento de recursos de orígenes cruzados, es decir que es una política que determinará si un servidor externo al actual está autorizado a pedir un recurso, si no lo está se mostrará un breve mensaje

```
...Blocked by CORS Policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present
```

**¿significa que el server indique que recibe?**

En realidad, no, pues el **servidor indica que recibe el cliente**, si el servidor no especifica un tipo MIME, se usará el tipo MIME del archivo solicitado, es decir, pongámonos en una situación:

- Se solicita un archivo, el cual tiene una extensión `.css`, pero el servidor especifica que debe ser interpretado con tipo MIME `text/html`

Entonces ¿A quién le hacemos caso?

R: **Al servidor**

Pues, el archivo puede tener una extensión específica, pero si el servidor pide que se interprete con un tipo diferente, no hay nada que discutir

Comment: en mi caso el **backend** esta desplegado en un servidor, del cual no tengo idea en que puerto este y el **front** esta de manera local solo haciendo peticiones a dicho servidor, por lo tanto ambas formas seguras, dependiendo de la configuración realizada en el **backend**

Comment: también mencionas que `Content-Type` debería ser enviada por el servidor, no entiendo del todo como debería hacer dicho proceso ya que con poca experiencia en **backend**, ¿significa que el server indique que recibe ? y ¿Que el cliente solo lo envie como el ejemplo que muestras?, ¿De casualidad tienes algun articulo o algo que pueda darme una introducción a eso?

Comment: En realidad [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) es uno de los headers que tienen sentido tanto para requests como para responses. Es de hecho de los pocos  headers explícitamente permitidos para los Request CORS. Fíjate que hasta los formularios permiten establecer si prefieren viar la info como url encoded o como form-data

Answer (score 3):

El error te está diciendo que falló el preflight, que es un request de tipo OPTIONS que precede a un request cuando entran en juego las reglas de *Cross Origin Resource Sharing* (CORS).

En ese preflight el servidor no respondió con las cabeceras necesarias para hacer siquiera el intento de proseguir con el flujo.

¿Por qué tu otra petición no tuvo el mismo problema? Por la misma razón que puedes incluir una imagen, un css o una tipografía de otro sitio. [Hay requests que se consideran inofensivos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests) y uno de los requisitos para que se consideren como tal es el `Content-Type`:

> The only allowed values for the Content-Type header are:
>
> - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> - multipart/form-data
> - text/plain

En cualquier otro caso debe comprobarse lo que el preflight te informa que no se cumplió.

Si el servidor al que estás enviando datos tiene una política CORS que no permite enviarle JSON, pero al mismo tiempo parsea sin problema un json enviado como texto plano, sin molestarse en verificar el header `Content-Type`, **entonces la respuesta es sí**, puedes eludir la restricción CORS valiéndote del `text/plain` gracias a que ese backend tiene una falla de seguridad no menor.

#### Es CORS como un Access Controll List?

CORS se inventó para poder configurar de manera granular el contenido que puede ir y venir dependiendo de su origen, ubicación, tipo, etc. Como si fuera una lista de excepciones a la regla. En otras palabras, se usa CORS para que el browser sepa en qué circunstancias puede dejarte, como visitante, saltarte la regla general Same Origin Policy, e interactuar con otro dominio, basado en las cabeceras que ese dominio le responde en el preflight.

Esta restricción no es un ACL del servidor, No es para proteger al servidor de que le inyecten o roben información. **Es para proteger al visitante**, a la luz de todo lo que programáticamente se puede hacer tras bambalinas cuando visitas un sitio.

Si el peligro proviniera de enviar un payload malicioso al servidor, hay maneras mucho más rápidas de saltarse el Same Origin Policy (curl, Postman, y la librería de requests que está en todos los lenguajes).

Cuando el servidor no responde con las cabeceras que confirman que tu origen es aceptado, o que las cabeceras que quieres enviar son aceptadas, o que permite enviar tus credenciales, te está diciendo: "**no se supone que me mandes datos, no hables con extraños**" y no "*usted no tiene permiso para ver mi información confidencial*".

Te recomiendo que hagas la prueba ejecutando el `fetch` con la opción `no-cors`. Algo como:

```
const result = await fetch('https://backend.com', {
  method: 'POST',
  mode: 'no-cors',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ "email": "juanito@mail.com"}),
});
```

Si inspeccionas en tus dev tools el request se manda, pero fíjate en las cabeceras que se mandaron: el browser reemplazó tu `application/json` por `text/plain`. (y el request se ha vuelto opaco, o sea no sabes qué te habrán respondido o si les llegó). Al servidor por supuesto que le llega, pero como es texto plano no debiera parsearlo, y menos responder con un token si es ese tipo de endpoint.

Comment: En este caso, sería agregar la configuración al **backend** (que esta en un servidor remoto) de que acepte un tipo u el otro, ya que mi fron esta de manera local para pruebas y no se tiene planeado subir hasta que este mas avanzado.

Comment: para desarrollo local y backend remoto es más práctico levantar un proxy local. El devserver de webpack trae uno incorporado. Las peticiones de tu browser al proxy son Same Origin, y las del proxy hacia la internet no están sujetas a las restricciones de un browser. Para la hora de subir tu cliente de front a producción (o desarrollo pero públicamente visible) entonces sí debieran configurar CORS en el backend.